# Decrease string length with binary only, making it as short as possible

Tags: php

So today I made a bet with my professor on who can make a string as short as possible with binary only (Between him and me). I totally took the challenge.
The "string" is a 10000 character long string with 1, 2, 3 and 4 only. List here: https://pastebin.com/raw/AnTnbxPA

So, I tried the following:

```
if (strtolower($argv[0]) == "a") { // Averagely 3.4x longer
    $b = fopen("output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $letters = str_split($a);
    $hh = "";
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        for ($k = 0 ; $k < $letter; $k++) {
            $hh .= "1";
        }
        $hh .= "0";
    }
    fwrite($b, $hh);
    fclose($b);
}
```

and

```
if (strtolower($argv[0]) == "b") { // Averagely 5.9x longer
    $b = fopen("output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $letters = str_split($a);
    $hh = [];
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        $data = unpack('H*', $letter);
        $hh[] = base_convert($data[1], 16, 2);
    }
    fwrite($b, implode('', $hh));
    fclose($b);
}
```

and

```
if (strtolower($argv[0]) == "c") { // Averagely 2.9x longer
    $b = fopen("output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $letters = str_split($a);
    $hh = [];
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        $data = unpack('H*', $letter);
        $hh[] = str_replace('110', '', base_convert($data[1], 16, 2));
    }
    fwrite($b, implode('', $hh));
    fclose($b);
}
```

and the last one:

```
if (strtolower($argv[0]) == "d") { // Averagely 1.9x longer
    $b = fopen("output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $letters = str_split($a);
    $hh = "";
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        if ($letter == "1") {
            $hh .= "00";
        }
        if ($letter == "2") {
            $hh .= "01";
        }
        if ($letter == "3") {
            $hh .= "10";
        }
        if ($letter == "4") {
            $hh .= "11";
        }
    }
    fwrite($b, $hh);
    fclose($b);
}
```

So, I need to make that string with numbers only as small as possible, using only 1's and 0's. I really intend of beating my professor up, he always told me to never be scared to ask anyone for help, so here I am! I hope you'll be interested in helping me. (I may not use any third party libraries) Thank you!!!

Comment: _beating my professor up_... that's maybe a bit drastic, don't you think? :-)

Comment: @jibsteroos sssssh :p

Comment: TBH I think the last one may be the best - although as each character is converted into a 2 digit binary number, how does it average out at 1.9x longer?

Comment: I have no clue, I came out to 19457 characters somehow... @NigelRen

Comment: @AaronJonk did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation is the longest way to represent data because it uses only `1` and `0`. Therefore you can't create a shorter string using it.

If for you is correct to have the resulting string longer than the original, try this code:

```
$letters = str_split($a);
$strNew = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($letters); $i++)
{
    $n = 0;
    while($n < 10)
    {
        $n++;

        if($letters[$i+$n] != $letters[$i])
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    $strNew .= "$n$letters[$i]";
}

$characters = str_split($strNew);
$binary = [];
foreach ($characters as $character) {
    $data = unpack('H*', $character);
    $binary[] = base_convert($data[1], 10, 2);
}
echo $str01 = implode('', $binary);
```

It counts the number of consequent equals char and store it as a two char string like `31` that means "3 times 1", then convert the whole resulting string in binary.

Comment: I have to havo it shorter, or well, as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider compression, if the rules of your bet allow it:

For instance a section of your string "44444" might look like this in binary (using 3 bits):
`100100100100100`.

But you could represent it like "54" (five 4s here):
`101100`.

Compressing the entire thing to a much smaller file in this way. Of course this means you have to be allowed to uncompress it to return to the original state.

Comment: `101100` is longer than `44444` so if I correctly understand the question (get a shorter string than the original), this example isn't useful. Tell me if I'm wrong

Comment: I might be misunderstanding too, but I read it as the original string's binary representation's size is what's counted. Otherwise there's no shorter way to make it with binary at all!

Comment: @user2342558, the question actually says *a string as short as possible*

Comment: @NigelRen I see it but the title start as `Decrease string length with binary only`. It confuse a little.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following approach. Your binary number would have four sections:

**range1_1...range1_nrange_2_1...range2_mrange3_1...range3_krange4_1...range4_k**

The number of ranges will be represented on a constant number of bits and range1_1 would consist of two constant-sized section of bits, representing the starting and the ending of the given range. This is of course, assuming that you have many subsequent numbers having the same value. If those values are varying, then you will need to find some patterns and apply the same idea as above.